# Does Apple make its own lenses for iPhone cameras?

Tags: lens, lens-design, iphone, smartphone, apple

Does Apple make its own lenses for iPhone cameras? Or, does it at least *design* them? If not, does it source from a lens maker like Zeiss, or a camera maker like Canon?

Answer (score 2):

A quick google search reveals no hard information but something like this:

"The lens modules themselves bear no such identification, but Taiwanese manufacturers Largan Precision and Genius Electronic Optical have been named as suppliers for the iPhone 4, 4S and 5 -- with the iPhone 5 manifests also listing Japanese optical manufacturer Kantatsu."
 - http://science.opposingviews.com/manufactures-apples-iphone-camera-18562.html

and:
"According to a new report, Apple may shift 30 percent of its orders for the lens modules for the iPhone 6s away from current contractors Largan Precision to Japanese rival company Kantatsu, over Largan’s refusal to lower its prices."
 - http://www.cultofmac.com/390193/apple-shows-iphone-6s-lens-supplier-whos-boss/

and:
"Both Largan Precision and Genius Electronic Optical are said to be supplying smartphone lenses for the iPhone, Taiwan Economic News reported on Monday"
http://appleinsider.com/articles/11/09/05/two_lens_makers_tapped_by_apple_to_supply_8mp_cameras_for_iphone_5

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone lenses are designed in-house.  They are several element designs, approximately 5, and each element is a double-sided and radical aspherical element.

source: Optics 241, Geometrical Optics - lecture notes.